# Is there a way to filter MAC addresses on an iPhone hotspot?

Tags: iphone, security, internet-sharing

I am using an iPhone 7 as a Personal Hotspot. Every now and then, the line at the top of the screen which says how many connections there are goes up. I don't know if someone else is accessing the hotspot, but I only use it for my laptop and would like to filter connections to the hotspot to drop everything except my laptop.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone 7 forces the use of a password, which can be changed at will, to connect to the Personal Hotspot. Does your phone not have this option? My carrier is AT&T.

[image]